# Ruby on Rails: Invalid nested record gets saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I've got a model `NewsItem` that `has_many :attachments`. In the new NewsItem-form, the user can create the item's attachments using a nested form.

An `Attachment` consists of a `title` and a `file` (which is uploaded). The model performs validations on the presence of both of those fields.

However, if I keep the fields for a new attachment blank, and hit the submit button, I do get the correct error messages ("title must not be blank", etc...), but the attachment does still get saved with both (invalid) values nevertheless.

The only relevant code, I can come up with is the part where I call `@news.save` in the `create` method of the `NewsItemController`:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @news.save
    flash[:success] = t( 'news.flash.created' )
    format.html { redirect_to news_index_path }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
  end
end
```

Everything else should be handled by rails (News `accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, :allow_destroy => true`).

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

**Update:**

It seems like the `:reject_if`-parameter of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is pretty much what I need. Unfortunately, you can only silently "ignore" invalid records. I want the user to receive an error message if either of the two fields is blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [:inverse_of](http://mediumexposure.com/better-memory-associations-inverseof/):

```
class NewsItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, :inverse_of => :news_item
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :news_item, :inverse_of => :attachments
end
```

Comment: The problem is, I simplyfied things a bit for the question: This whole thing is a polymorphic relationship and goes through an Attachable interface: `Attachment belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true` and `news_item has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy`

Comment: just found that the rails docs say, that :inverse_of does not work with polymorphic associations, any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I have not. BTW, you should update your question with information that you are using `polymorphic`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by doing a pretty hard workaround.

I now **do** use :reject_if to reject invalid attachments. However, since this alone does not produce the desired error-messages, I have to manually check the attachments-part of the params hash for errors by constructing a new Attachment for each entry and checking if it is valid. I then fill the errors-array of the parent object with the related error-messages.

A rather inconvenient solution I know... but at least it works.